# MySQL Select customers without an active order with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

So, I am trying to select customers that are completely inactive with MySQL join. I have the following statement that selects all the customers with an active service order.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.* FROM users u INNER JOIN orders o ON o.assigned=u.id AND o.status!=0
```

This works just fine. But now I am trying to select customers who previously had an order but the order became deactivated (o.status would equate to the value 0). I have the following statement (which is close) but it is returning customers who still have an active order, but have another order which was deactivated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.* FROM users u INNER JOIN orders o ON o.assigned=u.id AND o.status!=1
```

So in layman term, basically a customer can have multiple service orders. Every service being independent from one another, I want to select the customers who are COMPLETELY deactivated. For example:

Susan has 2 service orders, 1 which is activated and the other deactivated. Right now, Susan is being populated in the list of users who are deactivated and that is incorrect. Only the customers whose orders are completely deactivated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.* 
  FROM users u 
  LEFT
  JOIN orders o 
    ON o.assigned=u.id 
   AND o.status!=0
 WHERE o.assigned IS NULL;
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

In order to account for this scenario, you need to do a WHERE clause that would include the opposite SELECT statement.

For example:

```
select distinct u.* from users u inner join orders o 
on o.assigned=u.id and o.status!=1
where u.id != (select distinct s.id from users s inner join orders r 
on r.assigned = s.id and r.status!=0 where s.id == u.id)
```